# GMail: Create filter to skip inbox but send signal to sender that message was opened

Tags: gmail

Scenario:

- I'm subscribed to a mailing list.
- I want to read the messages when it suits me. Sort of like binge watching on Netflix.
- Setting up a filter to skip the inbox, means no images will be displayed and the sender doesn't get a signal that I opened it.
- There may be months between my binges and thus months without that signal going back.
- This means I risk that the sender will automatically unsubscribe me as part of a regular (automatic) list pruning practice.

Question:
Is there a way to get GMail to automatically open images when skipping the inbox so the sender thinks I'm opening their messages?

Comment: do mailing list purge based on not getting a read receipt? I always block read receipts.

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep that would be bizarre. Lists try to grow not shrink.  They would normally only remove if you unsubscribe or they get bounce backs.  I am hard pressed to believe that they care if you open vis a vis removing you, but maybe Marjan knows something about this list that we don't.

Comment: @BlindSpots: no, it's not bizarre. Mailing lists don't exist to just grow. They are a means to an end: getting support (good causes) and nurturing prospects until they convert to customers. Mailing list providers do cost, you know. As soon as you grow above the free tier (if they have one), prices (subscription or flat fees) go up with the number of subscribers and messages sent. So inactive subscribers are a money sink. Pruning mailing lists is a practice to keep costs down and more accurately gauge the appeal and effectiveness of what you're sending out.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: depends on the purpose of the mailing list. There are many mailing lists run by people who are mostly scratching their own itch and staying below the limits that would drive them out of a free tier with a mailing list provider. With those, you probably don't have to worry about being unsubscribed. With others - where the mailing list is part of a wider marketing program, chances are they're pruning. See my comment to Blind Spots.

Comment: Fere tier mailing list that isn't read for many months.  Not in my wheelhouse.  I was open to the possibility that you could shed some light on it.